# C# ref return value and movable variables

Tags: c#, return, local, ref

According to https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf#page=436 C# can move variables around.

When you now look at the number store example here (at the bottom of the page) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns, I have the following question.

When the number store is moved around, will the ref return value/ref locals be corrected to point to the new location?

Or if I have an array of value types (struct) and I store the reference to one element in a ref local variable, is there a guarantee that the array and thus the referenced element can still be accessed correctly?

Comment: You are accessing an instance of the object.  The c# dispose method before removing an object checks to make sure there are no parents before removing.  So as long as there is a reference to the object it will still exist.

Comment: But do ref locals get updated, so that you don't need to pin objects to use ref local on one of it's elements?

Comment: I think that's the real question to ask - does the `ref` keyword use variable pinning when referring to a class, or is a `ref` variable actually a GC reference that will be updated as the variable moves?

Comment: The spec linked does say that `ref` and `out` are moveables. And considering they're not `unsafe`, having them be affected by GC would defeat the whole safety premise of the framework.